# apt-get update do nothing and can't open any http connection

Tags: debian, apt

Ì'm using debian stretch.

my `apt-get update` was work fine but now it try to connect to network but nothing happen.

my `sources.list` is:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main contrib non- free

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security/ stretch/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security/ stretch/updates main contrib non-free
```

[image]

and `prod.debian.map.fastly.net`  not open in my browser.

i try to disable ipv6 but still got the same error
[image]

and my wifi config
[image]

ip address result 
[image]

Comment: @GAD3R still the same problem

Comment: i think the problem is i can't connect to prod.debian.map.fastly.net

Comment: Please add the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`

Comment: @GAD3R  ### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main

Comment: Please read our FAQ. You are reposting questions you asked earlier on today.

Answer (score 2):

Let's see if it is a network problem.
Can you ping any other addresses?

```
ping 8.8.8.8
```

Let that go for a few seconds then CTRL+C

How about

```
ping google.com
```

and CTRL+C after a few seconds.

***Did one produce results and the other didn't?***

How did you connect to your internet access point??

- Did you pick the wireless AP from the drop down list and punch in your password?
- Or, did you manually configure your wireless connection?

Usually, disconnecting and then reconnecting fixes any kinks.
Does it connect for a few seconds to a few minutes then seem to stall out and not work? 
That usually points to a driver issue.

Have you installed the linux-firmware and linux-firmware-nonfree packages prior to this issue?

**This also seems kind of strange but just try it:**

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stretch main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stretch main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main contrib non- free

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security/ stretch/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security/ stretch/updates main contrib non-free
```

I added a / slash to the end of your soruces... Replace your list with a copy and paste of that above and see if that little quirk makes all the difference... It shouldn't but it is the only thing I saw different from my list... I used synaptic and it auto adds / to the end.

Comment: This conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77769/discussion-on-answer-by-mydarkthawts-apt-get-update-do-nothing-and-cant-open-an).